# Custom icon of running app from ".desktop" files not showing in dock when the desktop file is not in the applications folder (Ubuntu 17.10)

Tags: 17.10, icons, dock

Is there any way to make a custom `Icon=/path/file.png` be shown in dock when an app is running, without putting this `.desktop` file into `/usr/share/applications/` or `~/.local/share/applications/` folders ?

When `.desktop` file is in this folders the icon is shown correctly in dock, if it's just in any other folder - default icon is used. Icon on desktop file in nautilus is shown correctly through.

To clarify, I mean an icon of currently started app.

contents of `pre2.desktop`:

```
[Desktop Entry]
Version=1.0
Name=Prehistorik 2
Exec=dosbox -exit /home/user/dos/pre2/pre2.exe
Icon=/home/user/dos/pre2/pre2.svg
Terminal=false
Type=Application
```

just shows default icon (terminal with red X) when started.

Comment: Thanks, this was helpful for me where an icon wasn't showing in the dock for an application on the Desktop. I moved the shortcut to `~/.local/share/applications/` and that also made it show in the `Show Applications` list so I could Add to Favorites. Awesome. :)